# How can I test field validation?

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I have validation code which sets the error of the EditText when it doesn't satisfy the requirements.

```
field.setError(errorMessage);
```

This puts a little red circle with an exclamation point over the field, and when I touch the field, it displays my error message in a black box.  Great!

Now I want calabash to verify that the field failed validation.  For the moment at least I'm not concerned about the specific error message - I just want to know that an error message is displayed (or I would be happy to settle for the exclamation point, but since I can't find it using query in console, I suspect that would be harder).

This query:

```
query("android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer")
```

finds the error message window if it is present.

But it's only present if the field with the error has focus.  And I only set the error when the field *loses* focus.  That should be OK - my step can enter text into the field, leave the field, and come back.  When I do these things manually, the error message window is displayed.  What I have not yet been able to do is to write a step which does these things and reliably displays the error message window.  I have tried

```
query("EditText id:'#{field_id}'", {:setText => bad_text})
touch(query("* id:'#{another_field_id}'")[0])
touch(query("* id:'#{field_id}'")[0])
```

and

```
query("EditText id:'#{field_id}'", {:setText => bad_text})
system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_TAB")
touch(query("* id:'#{field_id}'")[0])
```

and both of these behave correctly for the first EditText, but fail to show the error message window for subsequent EditTexts.  Why?  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things with your calabash commands that could cause your tests to fail.

1) Do not use touch(query(...

```
# bad
touch(query("q"))
# good
touch("q")
```

2) Do not use 'setText' to simulate entering text

```
# bad
query("EditText", {:setText => 'bad_text'})
# good
enter_text("EditText", 'bad_text')
```

3) Do not use any input events

Input events like `system("#{default_device.adb_command} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_TAB")` are impossible for the user to perform on most devices, as very few Android devices have a physical keyboard. Use `press_user_action_button` to simulate the user pressing the input key appearing instead of the enter key.

Comment: Thank you!  This did the trick, specifically enter_text instead of set_text.  Can you point to a resource which explains why to use one instead of the other?

Comment: Using the 'setText approach' is just invoking the method setText on the matches of the query. This wont invoke any callbacks. Using `keyboard_enter_text` is the way to input text.

Comment: That makes sense, but I still have trouble understanding why it worked on the first field on the screen.  Thanks.